# Enumerating monomorphisms of finite-dimensional $\mathbb{F}_2$-algebras

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, finite-fields, algebras

I want to enumerate the monomorphisms of finite-dimensional $\mathbb{F}_2$-algebras.

Of course, each such monomorphism is a linear map between finite-dimensional $\mathbb{F}_2$-vector spaces, and so can be represented as a matrix with entries in $\mathbb{F}_2$. Since we are looking just at mononorphisms, the number of rows must be greater than or equal to the number of columns, and the columns must be linearly independent over $\mathbb{F}_2$.

**But how can I identify those matrices corresponding to algebra homomorphisms? Is there a simple way to do this?**

I hope to enumerate based on the dimension of each algebra. If $A$ and $B$ have dimension $m$ and $n$ respectively, then when $(m,n)$ is $(0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(0,2)$, there is clearly only one such monomorphism. But what about $(1,2)$?

There can be at most 3 monomorphisms, with entries $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(1,1)$ (these should be written as $2\times 1$ matrices). But where can I go from here?

Comment: You seem to be assuming that your algebras have a certain specific algebra structure that is determined only by their dimension.  Can you elaborate on that?  Typically a vector space admits many different algebra structures (which are not even all isomorphic).

Comment: @EricWofsey Unless I am mistaken, the finite-dimensional $\mathbb{F}_2$-algebras correspond to cubic arrays with entries in $\mathbb{F}_2$. So if we fix the dimensions $m$ and $n$ of fin. dim. algebras $A$ and $B$, then there are $2^{m^3+n^3}$ different algebra structures to choose for the pair $(A,B)$. Then the monomorphisms of *vector spaces* are the $n\times m$ matrices whose columns are lin. indep. But, with the algebra structures fixed, I am unsure how to determine which matrices preserve the chosen algebra structure. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I wouldn't expect there to be any particular shortcut to doing so in general.  This sounds like an XY problem--what is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @EricWofsey I'm trying to construct an $\mathbb{F}_2$-algebra $Q$ of countable dimension such that for each mono. $j:A\to B$ of fin. dim. algebras and each mono. $i:A\to Q$, there exists a mono. $k:B\to Q$ with $kj=i$. The general approach being to enumerate the mono's, construct $Q(1)$, $Q(2)$ etc. inductively and take colimit.

Comment: Alright, but to do that you don't have to *explicitly* enumerate the maps (unless you want an *explicit* construction of $Q$, which I wouldn't expect to be nice at all).  You just need to know there are only countably many of them.

Comment: @EricWofsey Hmmm.. the reason I was trying to explicitly enumerate them was as follows: we have an enumeration $j_n:A_n\to B_n$, $n\geq 1$, and want to find $Q(2)$ such that for each mono. $A_1\to Q(2)$ there exists a mono. $B_1\to Q(2)$ with the right commutativity requirement. How can I know that such a mono. $B_1\to Q(2)$ exists without finding it explicitly based on what $j_1$, $A_1$ and $B_1$ are? Some property of the category of $\mathbb{F}_2$-algebras? I'm sure I'm missing something

Comment: I mean, you'll have to write down some formula to construct something at some point, but to do so you don't necessarily need to know exactly what $j_1,A_1,$ and $B_1$ are.  You can just write down a formula in terms of them.  (For instance, to construct a disjoint union of two sets $X$ and $Y$, you don't have to explicitly know what the sets $X$ and $Y$ are, you can just write down a general formula like $X\times\{0\}\cup Y\times\{1\}$.)